# What is the difference between notificationManager.notify and startForeground in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

I am just curious to know what are the differences between `NotificationManager.notify` and `startForeground` in Android.

Comment: In our Foreground-Service case, we use `startForeground` if the service has no other notifications (cause at least one is required to keep it alive), else we just update using `NotificationManagerCompat.from(serviceContext)
                .notify(myId, builder.build());` technique.

Comment: For example, Android's `VpnService` provides its own notification till disconnected, but if you require the service alive for some other task even if VPN is disconnected you need to use `startForeground` method (if service runs in background without any activity open), but just first time and update later with `NotificationManager`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`NotificationManager.notify`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) you can post as many updates to a notification as you like including adjustments to progress bars via [`Noticiation.Builder.setProgress`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setProgress%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29) in this way you only show one notification to the User, and its the one required by `startForeground`.

When you want to update a Notification set by startForeground(), simply build a new notication and then use NotificationManager to notify it.

The KEY point is to use the same notification id.

I didn't test the scenario of repeatedly calling `startForeground()` to update the Notification, but I think that using `NotificationManager.notify` would be better.

Updating the Notification will not remove the Service from the foreground status (this can be done only by calling `stopForground`.

Here is an example:

```
private static final int notif_id=1;

@Override
public void onCreate (){
    this.startForeground();
}

private void startForeground() {
    startForeground(notif_id, getMyActivityNotification(""));
}

private Notification getMyActivityNotification(String text){
    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects
    // this notification
    CharSequence title = getText(R.string.title_activity);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyActivity.class), 0);

    return new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_b3)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent).getNotification();     
}

/**
 * this is the method that can be called to update the Notification
 */
private void updateNotification() {
    String text = "Some text that will update the notification";

    Notification notification = getMyActivityNotification(text);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notif_id, notification);
}
```

You can find more examples and clarification on `NotificationManager.notify` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735027/notificationmanager-notify-creating-notifications-that-are-initially-missing-c)

I'd also suggest you to refer this [page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) in order to understand more on `startForeground`

Usages of `startForeground` could be found [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.app.NotificationManager&method=notify)

Comment: Was looking at an app we support the other day and noticed that it regularly calls startForeground to update the notification without any issue.  So it appears that both startForeground and notificationManager.notify behave similarly (at least as far as users can tell).